# maven tomcat plugin - tomcat is not running

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am new to maven and I want to run my web app using maven tomcat plugin, I have created maven project and added dependency for tomcat in pom.xml. I tried to run build the project and every time it stops in middle of tomcat start.

My pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pratik.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestingProj</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestingProj Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>TestingProj</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!-- Config: contextPath and Port (Default - /SimpleMavenWebApp : 8080) -->
                <!--<configuration>
                     <path>/</path>
                     <port>8899</port>                
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the console message is

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestingProj Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) > compile @ TestingProj >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestingProj ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TestingProj ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ TestingProj <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ TestingProj ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/TestingProj
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at D:\seleniumRM\TestingProj\target\tomcat
Oct 06, 2016 4:28:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Oct 06, 2016 4:28:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Oct 06, 2016 4:28:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 06, 2016 4:28:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080e
```

Comment: Isn't it just running and waiting for a signal to terminate (or you to use it)?